# Making rest of view gray when using UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uisearchbar

I want to mimic what seem to be the standard UI for using the UISearchBar, and right now I trying to make the rest of the view gray, when I begin searching, and I tried doing that by just setting the background color of the view to gray, but I am using sections in my UITableView, and they are not turning gray. Anybody have any reasons why that is?

[image: UITableView when using searchbar]

Comment: Maybe add gray (RGBA 0 0 0 0.5) overlay view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing the section headers fade to gray is because they are drawn on top of the gray background, and are opaque; in other words, their `alpha` is 1.

If you're looking for a suggestion to get the effect you want, my first reflex would be to add an overlay `UIView` as a subview of the area you want to be "grayed out", and change its background color when certain events occur.  Something like this:

```
// You have to choose what view is the one that needs to be grayed out.
// I'll call the view you want to gray out "viewToBeGrayed"

UIView *grayOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewToBeGrayed.frame];

// Initially, the overlay should be clear
[grayOverlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[viewToBeGrayed addSubview:grayOverlay];
```

Then, when you want to "gray out" `viewToBeGrayed`, just change the background color of `grayOverlay` to some translucent gray value:

```
[grayOverlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5]];
```

Finally, when you want to get rid of the "grayed out" effect, just set the view back to clear:

```
[grayOverlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

That should be a good place to start.  Comment if you need any additional help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the standard `UISearchController` for your tableview search needs.

Comment: The link is no longer relevant. Please update or remove your answer.

Comment: Well the question itself is no longer relevant. But sure, I'll update my answer to reflect that you should NOT by any means try this anymore as the new UISearchController API is standard. Likewise, the accepted answer clearly explains how to accomplish such a thing. But thanks for reminding me 3 years later @Tanner

Comment: You're right. I apologize if I upset you, but SO strives to not have broken links. Thanks for improving your answer - it is much more useful for new users now.